# rowindex using variables instead of hard coding

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a bit of VBA to delete a contiguous range of rows within a table.  I found several example on how delete rows and most were with for selected row, or a selection of none contiguous rows.  In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490255/excel-vba-delete-selected-rows-in-table) it was set to loop through and delete one row at a time which would work.  In another example, they had the following line which did it all in one shot

```
rows("4:8").delete
```

Now this seemed ideal to me.  I have my start row set as a variable, and I have my last row set as a variable.

```
DIM First_Row as integer
DIM Last_Row as integer
    First_Row = 14
    Last_Row = First_Row + Application.worksheetfunction.MAx(Range("B:B")) -1

    Rows(First_Row:Last_Row).delete

'That last line is not working


    Rows("First_Row:Last_Row").delete

'nor the above
```

what is the proper syntax to delete a range of rows in one shot without a loop?

Comment: Note that row counting variables must be of type `Long` bacause Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done in different ways, for example:

```
Range(Cells(First_Row,1),Cells(Last_Row,1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Another, perhaps simpler way, is

```
Range(First_Row & ":" & Last_Row).Delete
```

You might want to use `Long` rather than `Integer` for your row number variables, since `Integer` can overflow with modern Excel.

Comment: just decoding what you are saying about long versus integer...integer can have a max value of 32767 and the maximum number of rows in current excel versions exceeds that?

Comment: Yes: As an experiment, `?rows.Count` evaluates to 1048576 in the immediate window (in Excel 2016, but it has been like that for a while now).

Comment: %(&*@&# FIDDLE STICKS!  If you do `Range(First_Row&":"&Last_Row).Delete` you get an error, but if you leave the spaces in `Range(First_Row & ":" & Last_Row).Delete` no error.  sometimes syntax can be so frustrating.

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that some old-style Basics used *type-suffixes* where e.g. `name$` was used for a string variable, and that is still there in a dusty corner of the syntax for backwards compatibility. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4958189/4996248) for more.